# How to ignore/remove a folder from Git using SmartGit/KitKraken

Tags: git, smartgit, gitkraken

My android apps generated build folder is part of my git repo, and I want to remove it or ignore it.

I am using smartgit and git kraken (comparing the two). How can I remove/ignore this folder using the GUI interface of these two programs? I have found a lot of topics on manually editing gitignore file to do this.

But I am wondering if the GUI clients can do this themselves.

Answer (score 3):

With SmartGit you should be able to just right-click the untracked folder in the **Repositories** view and invoke **Ignore** from the context-menu.